# Reference for Solution Value in MATLAB using CPLEX as solver

Tags: matlab, optimization, cplex

I am looking at solving optimizaton problems using MATLAB to model the problem and CPLEX as the solver. Everything works and I am able to get my solution. However lets say I have 3 optimization variables all of different sizes, when I obtain the solution, I get the values of all the variables in 1 variable which I now have to sought through to get the values for each inidivual variable. Now if I were doing this in python and one of my variables is x, I would just use value.x to get the value of the x variable. Is there a similar way to get the values for the individual optimization variables without have to manually sought it out myself. This is what I use to obtain my solution:

```
options = cplexoptimset('cplex');
options.timelimit = 300;
[sol3,fval3, exitflag3, output3] = cplexmiqp(PP.H, PP.f, PP.Aineq, PP.bineq, ...
PP.Aeq, PP.beq,[], [], [], PP.lb, PP.ub, ctype, [], options);
```

If I had 3 optim. variables x1, x2 and x3 which are not scalar but arrays, my solution is stored in sol3 as [x1 x2 x3]. I want to just reference each variable without doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To CPLEX a variable is just an index and CPLEX does not know about the fact that subsets of your variables are organized in arrays, list, matrices, etc. So in general, the answer is "you can't do that". However, you are using the toolbox API which is designed to be a drop-in replacement for the matlab toolbox functions and thus has limited functionality.

You could switch to the [class API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/examples_cplex.html). With this API you can explicitly create variables one by one or array by array and keep indices to the various variables. This is a bit more similar to what you would do in Python.